# ¿Cómo graficar con setInterval en chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, div, setinterval

Estoy intentando hacer una gráfica con *chart.js*, pero quiero que cada 5 segundos se actualice el valor que traigo de una base de datos con php. No sé como poner el div para poder hacerlo.
El valor que traigo de la Base de datos con php es `<?php echo $setpoint; ?>`.

```
<h1>Nivel del setpoint</h1>
<canvas id="grafica"></canvas> <!-- Libreria para gráficos -->
<script src="script.js"></script> <!-- Script que crea la gráfica-->

<script>
    const grafica = document.querySelector("#grafica");
    //etiquetas eje x:
    const etiquetas= ["Setpoint"]

    //declarando el conjunto de datos:
    //SetGraf= setpoint gráfico
    const setGraf={
        label: "Setpoint", //etiqueta
        data: [<?php echo $setpoint; ?>], //valor del setpoint
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', // Color de fondo
        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', // Color del borde
        borderWidth: 1,// Ancho del borde
    };

    new Chart (grafica,{
        type: 'bar', //tipo de gráfica
        data: {
            labels: etiquetas,
            datasets: [
                setGraf,
            ]
        },
        options:{
            scales:{
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks:{
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }],
            },
        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Pones setTimeout( function(){ location.reload(); }, 5000); y te refresca la página cada 5 segundos

Comment: yo no quiero toda la página, quiero solo el valor del php-

Comment: No puedes hacer eso con el código que has mostrado, pero ni de cerca. Te recomiendo buscar en google `fetch json php`